# testHitObject is returning an incorrect "true" value on the first few frames

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6, hittest

```
if I add the else statement I do receive the "not hit" in my output window, so it looks like the statement only returns true on the first few frames, when it is supposed to return false. Now my problem is that the code wants to remove child objects before they've even been created. I just want to achieve basic collision detection between the enemy and the bullet so that i can remove both children when an enemy is shot. Please keep in mind that there will be multiple enemies and bullets on the stage at a given time.
```

I seemed to narrow down my problem. What was happening was the instance of an enemy would still exist, after i used the removeChild() function. Only now I couldn't see it for some reason. And its x and y properties were equal to 0. Therefore if I moved the ship to x = 0, it would have an "invisible" enemy collide with it. So I think my problem is I am not removing the instance properly? if not could you please help me?

```
    `    <pre>


 var BulletsArr:Array = new Array();
    var EnemysArray:Array = new Array();

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        BulletsArr[i] = new Bullet();
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        EnemysArray[i] = new Enemy();
        //EnemysArray[i].x = 2000; //Fix
        //EnemysArray[i].y = 2000; //Fix
    }

    stage.addChild(Ship);

    Ship.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fnEnterFrame);

    function fnEnterFrame(event:Event)
    {
      txtScore.text = "Score: " + score;
    //Make Ship follow cursor
        Ship.x = stage.mouseX;

        //Boundries
        if (Ship.x > 500)
        {
            Ship.x = 550 - 50;
        }

        if (Ship.x <= 0)
        {
            Ship.x = 0 ;
        }

            for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            for(var p = 0; p < 5; p++)
            {
                if(BulletsArr[i].hitTestObject(EnemysArray[p]))
                {
                    remove(BulletsArr[i]);
                    removeChild(EnemysArray[p]);
                }

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
         {  
            BulletsArr[i].y -= 15;
         }

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
         {  
            EnemysArray[i].y += 5;
         }

    for(var z = 0; z < 5; z++)
            {
               if(Ship.hitTestObject(EnemysArray[z])
                 {
                    Ship.parent.removeChild(Ship);
                    EnemysArray[z].parent.removeChild(EnemysArray[z]);
                    trace("Game over");
                 }

            }
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{ 
var found:Boolean = false;
    for(var p = 0; p < 5; p++)
    {
        if(BulletsArr[i].hitTestObject(EnemysArray[p]))
        {
            BulletsArr[i].parent.removeChild(BulletsArr[i]);
            BulletsArr[i] = new Bullet();


            EnemysArray[p].parent.removeChild(EnemysArray[p]);
            EnemysArray[p] = new Enemy();
            //EnemysArray[p].x = 2000;//fix
            //EnemysArray[p].y = 2000;//fix

            score += 50;

            found = true;
            break;
        }

        if(found)
        {
            break;
        }
    }   
            }
        }

    var count_Enemys:int = 0;
    var Timer_3_sec:Timer = new Timer(3000, 0);
    Timer_3_sec.start();

    Timer_3_sec.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,spawn_ship);

    function spawn_ship(Event:TimerEvent):void
    {
       if(count_Enemys >= 5)
    {
        count_Enemys = 0;       
        EnemysArray[count_Enemys].x = fl_GenerateRandomNumber(450) + 70;
        EnemysArray[count_Enemys].y = 0 - fl_GenerateRandomNumber(250) - 100;
        addChild(EnemysArray[count_Enemys]);
        count_Enemys++;
    }
    else
    {       
        EnemysArray[count_Enemys].x = fl_GenerateRandomNumber(450) + 70;
        EnemysArray[count_Enemys].y = 0 - fl_GenerateRandomNumber(250) - 100;
        addChild(EnemysArray[count_Enemys]);
        count_Enemys++;
    }
}
        `</code>
```

Comment: There is surely much more code involved here than the few lines you have included? This doesn't give much information.

Comment: nothing can be deducted from that code except that that method does not make up hits. That method does not return incorrect values ever, the coder (in this example you) is the one feeding incorrectly the method always.

Comment: The code you are talking about is commented out. Please post the code in exactly the same way you are using it. And please post the rest of your code as well.